# Random forest probability for selecting members

Tags: r, regression, logistic, random-forest

I used random forest to predict whether a player will be selected for taking part in the Olympic Games, and  0 represented for not selected and 1 for yes. I got the prediction result, for example,Amy is 0 ,Bobby is 1 and Cindy is 1; Q1:how to judge whether Bobby has higher probability of being selected or c is more likely to be selected; for example, rank the people whose final prediction result is 1, The first person is the one who had the highest probability to take part in the Olympics.Q2: I am not sure whether use random forest is correct, I tried logistic regression before but there are 17 variables and they are highly correlated. Therefore, I used random forest. Is there a better method ? Thanks a lot. Have a nice day!
I tried the function below in r

```
> prob=predict(fit_rf,shujuu,type="prob")
> prob
        0     1
1   0.196 0.804
2   0.188 0.812
3   0.224 0.776
4   0.240 0.760
5   0.232 0.768
6   0.172 0.828
7   0.240 0.760
8   0.184 0.816
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What problems do you see with  random forest approach? What problems do you see with a logistic regression approach?